# SharePoint 2010 Dev Machine Deploy to Stage Machine

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, feature

Machine 1: Virtual Development box with Visual Studio 2010, SharePoint 2010 Foundations, Designer 2010.

Machine 2: SharePoint 2010 Enterprise (Staging Environment)

Question: Does Machine 2 need to have Visual Studio 2010 installed if I want to deploy features/solutions from Machine 1?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can install your .wsp's with PowerShell cmdlets:

Add-SPSolution
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607552.aspx

Install-SPSolution
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607534.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. To further my understanding though, if I really want to deploy from Visual Studio, do I then need to have it on both machines?

Comment: yes, but don't do that. Visual Studio is not deploying the solutions exactly as a good script will do. You won't be able to ensure it will works the same.

Comment: This is a common scenario at our company. We do all development on a dev box, deploy to a staging environment via PowerShell and test, rework any issues we come into, and then deploy to production (again via PowerShell).

Comment: That's how I am planning to do it now. I am in the infancy of SP2010 research and development at present.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @rjcup3 answer,

Other options:

- Install VS 2012. With VS 2012, you can remote publish without needing to install VS on Machine 2 or manually publishing your wsp package to Machine 2. That means, install VS 2012 on Machine 1, create your package, deploy your package to Machine 2.

  [Reference: SharePoint Developer Team Blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20150323053053/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2012/03/22/sharepoint-developer-tools-in-visual-studio-11-beta-part-2-feature-enhancements-to-support-sharepoint-online-development.aspx)
- Check out this [blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20130316151037/http://blog.ftechsoftware.com:80/blog/post/2011/03/23/SharePoint-2010-remote-development-with-Visual-Studio-2010.aspx). But, I have not personally used it.

Comment: that is fabulous. great news. though, qualified: only for sandboxed solutions.

Comment: Did not know this. ^ @1c1cle that's lame and unfortunate.

Comment: True; That is one of limitations of using remote publishing in VS 2012. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh370987(VS.110).aspx